# How to specify a date when the function will be available for calling?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, nft

I have not figured out yet how to open NFT minting after specific date. For example, if I deploy my smart contract right now, I want users to be able to mint NFT's starting from 1st January of 2022.

I came across `block.timestamp`, but I can't figure out a way how to use it.

Or would it to be better to just deploy the contract on 1st January?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`block.timestamp` is a global variable returning the time of the block when the function is executed (by sending a transaction). Or the current time if the function is called (by performing a read-only call).

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

contract MyContract {
    function mint() external {
        require(block.timestamp >= 1640995200, "Not yet available");
        // ... rest of your code
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I got it now! I did came across a question on how do I generate the timestamp for specific human-readable date, but found bunch of converters online when doing a quick google search.

Comment: @coriden The timestamp (also known as "unix timestamp") is a standardized date format. Its value is the amount of seconds (or milliseconds in some cases) since January 1st, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC. Many programming languages have a way to convert a human readable date to the timestamp (unfortunately, Solidity currently can do that only on a very limited basis - only from a relative expression such as "now + 1 year", but not from an absolute date such as "2021-12-31"). And, as you say, there are many online tools that can convert it as well.